# '&' requires l-value on &std::unique_ptr<>.get

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, lvalue

I am trying to use the function [NuiCreateSensorByIndex(int,INuiSensor**)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663848.aspx). I am trying not to use naked pointers, so I did `std::unique_ptr<INuiSensor> nui;` to make it an unique_ptr.
Now I want to acces this function, so I do the following: `hr = NuiCreateSensorByIndex(i, &nui.get());`, but this is wrong:

```
KinectManager.cpp:29: error: C2102: '&' requires l-value
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is right: although `std::unique_ptr<INuiSensor>` can be used to point to things, it is not an object a pointer to which is expected by the `NuiCreateSensorByIndex(int,INuiSensor**)` function. The reason the function wants a pointer to a pointer is that it wants to modify pointer's content by an assignment of this sort:

```
*ptrToPtr = somePtr;
```

If compiler let you pass a pointer to `std::unique_ptr<INuiSensor>`, this assignment would be invalid. That's why you need to create a temporary "naked" pointer, pass it to the function, and then assign the result back to `std::unique_ptr<INuiSensor>`.

Comment: There are more than one reason to argument a C function with pointer to pointer. In the absence of further information, I might guess that this function needs an array of pointers and the first argument may refer to size(in bytes) or number of elements of the array. Without proper documentation a lot of possibilities can be imagined.

Answer (score 0):

```
T* get() const;
```

`get` returns its pointer by *value*, so what you were doing was taking the address of a temporary (technically referred to as an rvalue), which isn't allowed.

To fix this, you should store that value within a variable:

```
INuiSensor* ptr = uni.get();

hr = NuiCreateSensorByIndex(i, &ptr);
```

Comment: This won't work. ptr will be a copy of the actual value in the unique_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of unique_ptr is to take control of ownership of resource. The pointer to pointer is to modify the address of the resource, which will change the ownership of the resource. One solution is to release the ownership first, then reclaim it, such as:

```
auto p = uni.release();
NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0, &p);
uni.reset(p);
```